# Insertion into database

Tags: php, sql

How do i get the query to insert my row from one table to another? I use the conventional insert select delete . Now the thing that works is deleting the trade. however the values are not updating in the new table. I used a constants in the second table because the tables have unmatched columns , what could be the problem here?

```
<?php 
//If(!isset($trade_id)){
        $trade_id= $_GET['id'];

//}

require_once('connect.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($database_hostname, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name) or exit("Error connecting to database");
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `trade_history1` (session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit,dateclose,close, profitandloss)
    SELECT session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, profitandloss,'null','null'
    FROM `opentrades`
    WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `opentrades` WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);

    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $mysqli->commit();
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Successfully deleted';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Unable to delete';
    $mysqli->rollback();

}


        // if we successfully delete this, we
$mysqli->close();

// bid price,offer price, size,type,
header('location:js.php');
?>
```

Comment: You're not checking the return code from `query`. Are you sure it'll throw an exception on failure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli

Comment: I'd suggest echoing out the query and running it in the database directly. Does it work? You're also not checking any return values from your `query()` calls, so you don't know if anything is failing.

Answer (score 0):

```
  use following code
        mysqli_execute();instead of mysqli_query();



            $mysqli->execute("INSERT INTO `trade_history1` (session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit,dateclose,close, profitandloss)
SELECT session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, profitandloss,'null','null'
FROM `opentrades`
WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
$mysqli->execute("DELETE FROM `opentrades` WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
```

Comment: Doesn't that run a prepared statement?

Comment: execute is not defined.

Comment: 'Use the following' is not an answer. Why don't you describe what is wrong with the OP question and explain why it is so.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about constants in sql query but it seems the order of insertion and selection in query as you are using last four as:

```
takeprofit, dateclose, close,  profitandloss
```

should be in order

```
takeprofit, 'null', 'null', profitandloss
```

Comment: Okay thanks i edited that ! but the insertion is still not happening , where might be tthe problem?

Answer (score 0):

A query that fails does not throw an exception. You have echo that query and execute it in phpmyadmin. Like this you can drill to the bottom.

You must use `mysqli_error()` to verify if the insert query executed correctly, before deleting the row.